# Ошибка при добавлении валидации в правила на Firebase

Tags: регулярные-выражения, firebase, валидация

Делаю валидацию строки, но фаербаза почему-то не принимает.

Подробнее на скриншотах:

[image: скриншот с фаербазы]

На валидаторе все нормально
[image: с валидатора]

Вообще не понимаю, что тут может быть не так

Comment: Удвойте все ``\``.

Comment: Публикуйте текст, а не картинки.

Comment: я невнимательно ответ прочитал сначала. Удвоил все \ , теперь все работает. Большое спасибо

Comment: Поделитесь ссылкой на regex101, чтобы ответ быстрее написать.

Comment: Вот ссылка https://regex101.com/r/ybc9LV/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Firebase регулярное выражение передаётся в виде строкового литерала, поэтому все обратные слеши нужно экранировать. Прямые слеши должны быть экранированы, так как эти символы используются для "разграничения" регулярного выражения ("regex delimiters").

Используйте

```
.matches(/^steam:\\/\\/joinlobby\\/[0-9]{2,5}\\/[0-9]{10,20}\\/[0-9]{10,20}$/)
                 ^^ ^^          ^^           ^^             ^^
```